# What does the phrase 'Getting a haircut' modify?

Tags: grammar

I found a sentence in 'Life's like that' from Reader's digest, May 2018. In the sentence, what does the phrase 'Gettting a haircut' modify?

> Getting a haircut, the barber asked me, what I do for a living.

Comment: It is common in conversation (and in conversational prose) to rely upon the participle's sense of ongoing action and omit **while** as unnecessary to convey the meaning.

Answer (score 3):

It's a dangling modifier. It shows a fairly common type of mistake.

Thinking pragmatically, 'I' was 'getting a haircut'. Given what we know about barbers, this is the only possible understanding.

However the structure of the sentence suggests 'the barber' was 'getting a haircut'! This kind of ambiguity is generally considered poor English, but can be fix by

- As I was getting a haircut, the barber asked me... (put the subject in the phrase)
- Getting a haircut, I was asked by the barber ... (switch between passive  and active to move the modifed word to the front)
- The barber asked me what I do for a living while he was cutting my hair (move the modifer)

Answer (score 1):

It modifies no phrase. While I was getting a haircut, the barber (a man who cuts men's hair), asked me what I do for a living (what my job is). The second comma should not be there.